# Crystal Reports - Subreport with stored procedure as datasource creates a new param and doesn't pass it to the stored proc

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Using Crystal Reports XI, I have a main report. In this report, I have a Formula Field named `XXXCompanyFilter`. This is set programmatically at run time and I want to pass it to a subreport.

I add a subreport that has a stored procedure as an input parameter. The parameter is named `@co`.

A Parameter Field is automatically created in my subreport called `@co`.

I return to my main report and right-click the subreport and choose `Change Subreport Links`. I choose the Formula Field `XXXCompanyFilter` from the `Available Fields` list and move it to the `Field(s) to link to:` list.

At this point I expect to be able to choose the subreport's `@co` parameter in the `Subreport parameter field to use:` drop down, but it is not there. I have unchecked the `Select data in subreport based on field:` checkbox.

[image]

I've tried selecting the `?Pm-@XXXCompanyFilter` option, and that (I think) causes a new subreport parameter to be created:

[image]

After that, I do get the new subreport parameter to show in the drop down:

[image]

However, this new parameter doesn't seem to do anything, and I'm still prompted to enter the `@co` subreport parameter whenever I run the report. If I enter a value for the `@co` parameter the report returns the data I expect.

I've created several subreports to see if the behavior changes. I've tried it with the subreport wizard and with subreports I've created normally. I always get a 2nd, non-useful subreport parameter and the `@co` parameter is never set, so I am prompted for it.

I feel like if I could select the `@co` parameter in the drop down list it would work as needed.

I've checked out multiple SO posts, and I've googled the issue but everything I find says I'm doing it right. What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to do to make the `@co` parameter available in the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by specifying a database field in the `Available Fields` list when creating the subreport link and following the instructions in my original post.

Apparently it just won't work if you specify a Formula Field in the `Available Fields` list. I can't find any documentation on this but that's the conclusion I come to after reaching a solution by trial and error.